# plt.figure() doesn't show any figure in this example code

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I'm new to python and programing and I'm trying to make a code to display an image with some data from a `.fits` file. I'm first trying to make this example I found from this site: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/generated/examples/io/plot_fits-image.html#sphx-glr-download-generated-examples-io-plot-fits-image-py. When I run it, it shows everything it should, except the figure, which is the most important part. How do I make the figure show up?

The code is the following:

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from astropy.visualization import astropy_mpl_style
    plt.style.use(astropy_mpl_style)



    from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
    from astropy.io import fits

    image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits')


    fits.info(image_file)


    image_data = fits.getdata(image_file, ext=0)


    print(image_data.shape)


    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
    plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: It just returns this:                                                                                                     
               Filename: /home/a_burmeister/.astropy/cache/download/py3/2c9202ae878ecfcb60878ceb63837f5f
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU     161   (891, 893)   int16   
  1  er.mask       1 TableHDU        25   1600R x 4C   [F6.2, F6.2, F6.2, F6.2]   
(893, 891)

Answer (score 0):

Appending `plt.show()` at the end of your code should work ...

Answer (score 0):

I ignored the fact that the figure was not showing up in the example and went straight to my `.fits` file. With that file the figure worked fine. Turns out there was probably something wrong with the example file.